# How to make my method return a Collection<Character> instead

Tags: java, hashmap, return-value

My method should be called

```
Public Collection<Character> mostCommonFirstWeighted()
```

but the way I solve the problem is to make it return

```
List<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>>
```

How do I fix this so my return statement is a collection of characters instead?

```
    public List<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> mostCommonFirstWeighted() {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for (String s : lst) {
            if (hashmap.get(s.charAt(0)) == null) {
                hashmap.put(s.charAt(0), 1);
            } else {
                hashmap.put(s.charAt(0), hashmap.get(s.charAt(0)).intValue() + 1);
            }
        }
        Integer largestVal = null;
        List<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> largestList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>>();
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> i : hashmap.entrySet()) {
            if (largestVal == null || largestVal < i.getValue()) {
                largestVal = i.getValue();
                largestList.clear();
                largestList.add(i);
            } else if (largestVal == i.getValue()) {
                largestList.add(i);
            }
        }
        return largestList;
    }

}
```

Sample input: [and, and, and, and, these, those, their, boxes, boxes]

Expected result: [a]

What I get: [a=4]

Comment: don't you think you should give an example also about what your inputs and output should look like. I mean sample parameters !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
    List<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> largestList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>>();
```

to

```
    List<Character> largestList = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

And `largestList.add(i);` (both of them) to `largestList.add(i.getKey());`

Comment: When I change it to largestList.add(i) I get the error: add (java.lang.Character) in List cannot be applied to (java.lang.Integer)

Comment: @FatFockFrank sorry about that: it should be `i.getKey()`. (I made the change)